# setContentView() function alternatives in C#

Tags: c#, android, winforms

I am Android developer. When I want to change current layout (and functions assigned to it) in the `Activity` I use `setContentView()` method. Is there any similar function (to `setContentView()`) in C#, which gonna make me able to change layout (all the buttons, labels, etc., theirs position, names, ids, ...) in `Form` without opening new window and closing current one? I make fullscreen game, so...

I do not want to generate items dynamically if that isn't necessary. I tried Google search, but unsuccessfully...

Edit(from Selvin): In fact question is: What is the `android.app.Activity.setContentView` replacement in `System.Windows.Forms.Form` (and prolly has nothing to do with Xamarin )

Comment: Dear downvoter, please ask me if you do not know what I write about. I think I wrote everything clear

Comment: `Form.Controls.Clear(); Form.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl());` where MyUserControl is your control derived from UserControl (this shoul be similar to layout/fragment concept from Android)

Comment: You're making the mistake of trying to get winforms to act the same way as an android application and there is a very big difference between activities and forms, You are better off either having different forms for each different task, using an actual game engine such as mono/xna, or better defining your question as to why you think you need to use the same window

Comment: @Sayse Ok, I only wanted to give an example... I can't have 43 different forms and for each change close fullscreen and then reopen it....

Comment: @Ty221 - You shouldn't need to, you have one main form that should open other forms as required, if that is 43 completely different operations then yes you would need 43 forms, if they share common functionality you can create base form classes or generic forms. But then again, winforms isn't designed to create games

Comment: @Sayse So what should I use to do so? XNA?

Comment: There are a few options - XNA, Monogame, Unity, UDK (this isn't C# tho), and im sure there are more

Comment: Thank you, please write that as an answer, I want to accept it

Comment: @Ty221 - Thank you but that kind of answer wouldn't be a valid answer on StackOverflow as technically it doesn't answer your original question and it is just a resource recommendation. You'd be better off either deleting your question or providing your own answer as to how you solved your problem